# Creating an array of types that differ only in the `const` generic argument

Tags: rust

I have a struct

```rust
pub struct A<B, const C: u8> {
    pub _a: PhantomData<B>,
}

impl<B, const C: u8> A<B, C> {
    pub(crate) fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            _a: core::marker::PhantomData,
        }
    }
}
```

I want to wrap it with my struct and create array from it

```rust
pub struct MyA<B, const C: u8> {
    pub a: A<B, C>,
}

type B1 = u8;
type B2 = u8;

fn main() {

  let _arr: [MyA<_,_>; 4] = [
  MyA{a: A::<B1,1>::new()},
  MyA{a: A::<B1,2>::new()},
  MyA{a: A::<B2,1>::new()},
  MyA{a: A::<B2,2>::new()},
  ];
  
}
```

And I get an error

```rust
error[E0747]: type provided when a constant was expected
 --> src/main.rs:8:20
  |
8 |   let _arr: [MyA<_,_>; 4] = [
  |                    ^
  |
  = help: const arguments cannot yet be inferred with `_`
```

Is there some way to combine such structures into an array?

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7ffa70839d7025d0f242a02e57abe5d9)

Comment: Just omit the type altogether (or specify the constant).

Comment: Even if you could specify it, your array elements have different types.

Comment: You're trying to put different types together into a single array. This cannot work. It has nothing to do with inference either, there's no correct type to infer here - this doesn't compile if you say it's `MyA<_, 1>`, or `MyA<_, 2>`.

Comment: Also the type of `_arr` should be `[MyA<_,_>; 4]` if anything, not a single `MyA<_,_>`.

Comment: But if I [make](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1eb343cef3242971b33815f3447c3786) all the constants the same, the code compiles fine. Is this the only thing that affects the difference in types?

Comment: @NikitaKoss Because `B1` and `B2` are the *same* type, `u8`. `type T = ...` doesn't create a new type, only an alias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with const argument inference. There is no valid type to infer here. The mechanism of inference is the compiler finding the explicit type to put instead of you; there still has to be an explicit type that you might've written by hand for that works for the compiler to find.<sup>1</sup>

Arrays in Rust are homogenous, so each element has to have the same type. To fit `MyA{a: A::<B1,1>::new()}`, it has to be `MyA<u8, 1>`. But to fit `MyA{a: A::<B1,2>::new()}` it has to be `MyA<u8, 2>`. So it can be neither. Both of these fail to compile:

```rust
let _arr: [MyA<_,1>; 4] = [
    MyA{a: A::<B1,1>::new()},
    MyA{a: A::<B1,2>::new()}, // error[E0308]: mismatched types, expected A<_,1>, found A<_,2>
    MyA{a: A::<B2,1>::new()},
    MyA{a: A::<B2,2>::new()}, // error[E0308]: mismatched types, expected A<_,1>, found A<_,2>
];
```

```rust
let _arr: [MyA<_,2>; 4] = [
    MyA{a: A::<B1,1>::new()}, // error[E0308]: mismatched types, expected A<_,2>, found A<_,1>
    MyA{a: A::<B1,2>::new()},
    MyA{a: A::<B2,1>::new()}, // error[E0308]: mismatched types, expected A<_,2>, found A<_,1>
    MyA{a: A::<B2,2>::new()}, 
];
```

The key here is that **`A<B, 1>` and `A<B, 2>` are completely different types**. The compiler will not allow you to assign values of one to the other without some manual conversion.

There's a number of things you can do to work around this, and the best one will depend on what you're trying to actually achieve with that array.

### Enum

The direct Rusty thing to do would be to wrap the elements in an enum and have an array of those:

```rust
pub enum MyAEnum<B> {
    C1(MyA<B, 1>),
    C2(MyA<B, 2>),
}

fn main() {
  let _arr: [MyAEnum<_>; 4] = [
      MyAEnum::C1(MyA{a: A::<B1,1>::new()}),
      MyAEnum::C2(MyA{a: A::<B1,2>::new()}),
      MyAEnum::C1(MyA{a: A::<B2,1>::new()}),
      MyAEnum::C2(MyA{a: A::<B2,2>::new()}),
  ];
}
```

You can then pass this around and `match` on the variant before use.

### `dyn` trait

Another one would be to encapsulate the behaviour of your struct in a trait, and box it as an object type.

```rust
pub trait MyATrait<B> { }

impl<B, const C: u8> MyATrait<B> for MyA<B, C> { }

fn main() {
  let _arr: [Box<dyn MyATrait<_>>; 4] = [
      Box::new(MyA{a: A::<B1,1>::new()}),
      Box::new(MyA{a: A::<B1,2>::new()}),
      Box::new(MyA{a: A::<B2,1>::new()}),
      Box::new(MyA{a: A::<B2,2>::new()}),
  ];
}
```

You can pass this around and then interact with the values via the trait.

---

1. Barring cases where a type might be unspeakable. For example, you can't write the concrete types of closures by hand. But for this question's purposes that statement is sufficient.

Comment: In my case, all of these elements have a trait that I want to use. It would be convenient for me to access them by indexes or through an iterator. I think that in this case, I should use the second option. And the array should not be made up of structures, but from their references?

Comment: If they implement a common trait then `dyn` is the easiest way to go. The downside of that is that it moves the objects to the heap and introduces a virtual call when you use those boxes.